# Efficient solution for storing many small integers

Tags: database, storage

I am going to generate a dataset that will contain around 7*10^11 integers. Each integer will be between 0-1000. Uncompressed, this will require storage of about 14 TB (short integers).

Is there an efficient database solution with built-in compression for this kind of information?

Comment: what do you need to do with this data once you put it in the database? ie: do you need good random read perf / good slice access / best write perf, but not necessarily read perf?

Comment: Also you're an order of magnitude off with the numbers, 7e10 shorts is 1.4TB not 14TB

Comment: Are the value evenly distributed between 0 or 1000, or are some numbers more likely to appear?  Is one number likely to depend on the prior number?

Answer (score 2):

Are you only storing the integers, or something else?

Why wouldn't you make a table with two columns:

- Number: being 0 to 1000
- Count: being how many times this appeared in the set

Do you have some unstated requirement, such as having to keep them in order?

Answer (score 1):

A storage of 10 bits would cover an integer up to 1024, which is greater than your expected max value of 1000.  So, you could use a multi-bit column which only has a width of 10.  This would reduce your storage overhead to only 875 GB, instead of 14 TB.

In Postgres, there is a `BIT` type which should work here.  I would expect that most databases would have something similar to this.

Comment: @Dreuhn There is generally no such thing as order in a SQL table.  If you want to maintain order, you'll need another column to do that.  For example, you could store the datetime of insert.

Comment: That would unfortunately lead to an unacceptable amount of used storage.